# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language & Usage's [second moderator election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: KitFox] [image: simchona]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://english.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/495069/0).

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators.

Comment: That's it? Where are the fireworks?

Comment: @Mitch: the fireworks generally start about the time they start closing popular but unproductive questions...

Comment: @Mitch: Fireworks? _Fireworks!?_  Forget the fireworks – where's my coffee cake??

Comment: @Shog9 Are you implying that the previous moderators were unable to detect and close *popular but unproductive questions*?

Comment: @Meysam: are you implying EL&U has been suffering from a severe shortage of fireworks?

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Congratulations! :D

Comment: @Shog9 Should we ask a question about fireworks on the main site, as way to compensate the shortage of fireworks? (This reminds what they say about something else that is not done, but for which people spend many time to speak of. `;)`)

Comment: Congratulations to the winners and all contestants! Thanks for your commitment to this site!